# merge blank columns based on first cell value

Tags: excel, vba

i want to merge blank cells "O2" columns based on first cell value i tried below code,

```
Dim rng as range
Range("O2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
mergecells:
For Each rng In Selection
    IF rng.Value = rng.offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
        Range(rng, rng.offset(1, 0)).Merge
        GoTo mergecells
    End If
Next
```

But it's kinda not working, please help or suggest me any code.

NOTE: i have huge data set it's just a part of that VBA hence i need this in VBA codes.

Thankyou everyone.

Comment: Your `IF rng.Value = rng.offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then` is the issue.  If you are trying to test rng = "" and rng.Offset(1, 0) = "" use `IF rng.Value = "" and rng.offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then`
R

Comment: And fwiw that label/ GoTo structure is probably going to cause an infinite loop

Comment: thankyou so much chris neilsen, i am a student of VBA as a intermediate...you saved me i was trying to searching this for since 2 days. thankyou so much :)